# I want to retrieve array data and post it in order while I am inside a loop

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, loops, woocommerce

I have a checkout which runs on woocommerce / wordpress, I need to be able to output the contents of the basket into 3 input form fields on the checkout review page.

I have a loop which gets the product names, creates an input box and enters the product name into the input field.

```
    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
        $_product = apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key);
        if ($_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters('woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key)) {
            ?>
            <?php $productname = $_product->get_title(); ?>
            <input type="text" id=" " name="" value="<?php echo $productname; ?>" maxlength="100"/>
        <?php }
    }
```

I however need these input fields created to have specific ID's, you are only ever only allowed to order no more 3 products through this site so I have 3 ID's that are to be assigned to these fields. I have created an array with the ID's

```
$inputid = array ("powf_9c859612fda4e61180eb5065f38aea21", "powf_b496ed1efda4e61180eb5065f38aea21", "powf_1625303afda4e61180eb5065f38aea21");
```

What I am struggling with here is getting the ID's into the outputted html input fields. So that when they are created the markup should look something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="powf_9c859612fda4e61180eb5065f38aea21" name="" value="Product Name 1" maxlength="100"/>

<input type="text" id="powf_b496ed1efda4e61180eb5065f38aea21" name="" value="Product Name 2" maxlength="100"/>

<input type="text" id="powf_1625303afda4e61180eb5065f38aea21" name="" value="Product Name 3" maxlength="100"/>
```

Obviously if someone only has 1 or 2 items in their basket it should only still create the necessary fields.

Any help would be great thanks, I've been stuck on this for far too long!

Comment: Create a foreach loop with $inputid array to print desired numbers of cart products input field.@J.Gill

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working by approaching it in a different way.

Rather than having an array handle my form ID's and a loop handling my product names, I removed the original ID array and use my loop to create an array and add a product into that array every loop.

Then I just have my input fields echo out the array results from 0,1 and 2.

Like this:

```
foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
                $_product = apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key);
                if ($_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters('woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key)) {
                    ?>
                    <?php $productname = $_product->get_title(); ?>
                    <?php $array[] = $productname; ?>
                <?php }
            }

<input type="text" id="powf_9c859612fda4e61180eb5065f38aea21" name="powf_9c859612fda4e61180eb5065f38aea21" value="<?php echo $array[0]; ?>" maxlength="100" />
```